# Como validar se dados são maior ou menor que o anterior num DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, classificação

boa noite! Estou começando o desafio de migrar do Excel para o Python, e me deparei com um problema do qual gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver.

Eu tenho um DataFrame com algumas informações, onde na terceira coluna eu classifico como 1 se o dado da coluna "Idade" for maior que o anterior, e como 0 se for menor, conforme exemplo:

```
Nome    Idade   Class.
Lucas    15 
João     18      1
Joana    13      0
Mariana  15      1
```

Então, como João tem a idade maior que Lucas, classificou como 1. Como Joana tem a idade menor que o João, classifica como 0. Etc.

Gostaria de fazer isso de forma automática via código, mas não sei como montar. Pensei dessa forma, mas não sei como eu preencheria o "?" de forma que funcionasse.

```
dataset.values[ dataset > ? ] = 1
dataset.values[ dataset < ? ] = 0
```

Se tiver lido até aqui, obrigado!

Comment: Dá uma olhada no `df[coluna].diff()`. Caso não consiga, comente aqui.

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado!